# How to use python to calculate salaries?

Tags: python

I'm very, very new to code and my current class is sort of hitting us with all kinds of information at once. It's making a bit difficult to latch onto certain concepts. For this particular problem, our instructor wants us to write a code to calculate employee salaries based on hours worked. Here is the prompt: "A company wants a program that will calculate the weekly paycheck for an employee based on how many hours they worked. For this company, an employee earns $20 an hour for the first 40 hours that they work. The employee earns overtime, $30 an hour, for each hour they work above 40 hours."

He also gave us an example to work with: "If an employee works 60 hours in a week, they would earn $20/hr for the first 40 hours. Then they would earn $30/hr for the 20 hours they worked overtime. Therefore, they earned: ($20/hr * 40hrs) + ($30/hr * 20 hrs) = $800 + $600 = $1400 total."

Like I said, we were given a lot of information at once. I'm trying to use an if statement to make the code, but I know very well it's not written correctly. It's filled with all kinds of syntax errors. I'm just not sure what to do.

```
work_hours = str(input('Enter hours worked' ))
if (work_hours <= 40)
    salary = 20 * work_hours

if (work_hours > 40)
    over_salary = 30 * (work_hours - 40)
    reg_salary = 20 * 40 + over_salary

   print(reg_salary)
```

Comment: `work_hours = str(input('Enter hours worked' ))` This is your first problem.  `input()` returns a string, so the `str()` call is redundant.  You want `int()` instead, to convert the string answer to an integer.

Comment: Also note that the parentheses in your `if` statements are not used in Python.  That's a leftover from C, where they are needed.

Comment: Thank you! I knew I was doing that wrong; I had just remembered writing an input like that before, but I'm it was for names instead of numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Change that `str` to `int` and put colons after your `if` statements**

```
work_hours = int(input('Enter hours worked: ' ))
if work_hours <= 40:
    salary = 20 * work_hours

elif work_hours > 40:
    over_salary = 30 * (work_hours - 40)
    salary = 20 * 40 + over_salary

print(salary) # If I input 60 I get 1400
```

You can see that I changed the line `work_hours = str(input('Enter hours worked: ' ))` to `work_hours = int(input('Enter hours worked: ' ))`. By changing that line I made sure that the input would be interpreted as a number. I also put colons (`:`) after your `if` statements, which was the only `SyntaxError` I could find.

Comment: Should the if statement for overtime be an else statement instead?

Comment: Yes, but it's more complicated than that.  One branch computes `salary`, and one branch computes `reg_salary`, so the code will fail if you input 40 or below.  BOTH branches need to produce the same output variable.

Comment: Doesn't have to be, but unless you want to add another condition, should be a `else` or `elif` statement for the sake of readability. So, really, it's up to you.

Comment: That was a typo, I'm sorry. They should both be written as reg_salary. So if they're both reg_salary, it should be an else or am I still misunderstanding?

Comment: Yes, I edited my answer, I also removed the parentheses, as they were redundant.

Comment: From a software engineering standpoint, `reg_salary` is not the right name, because if there was overtime, the resulting number is NOT the regular salary.  It is the regular salary plus the overtime pay.  Thus, `salary` is probably a better name.

Answer (score 0):

Both branches of the `if` must produce the same variable, so you always have something to print.

```
work_hours = int(input('Enter hours worked: ' ))
if work_hours <= 40:
    salary = 20 * work_hours

else:
    over_salary = 30 * (work_hours - 40)
    salary = 20 * 40 + over_salary

print(salary)
```

Or, even better, do the overtime as an exception:

```
work_hours = int(input('Enter hours worked: ' ))
salary = 20 * work_hours

if work_hours > 40:
    over_salary = 10 * (work_hours - 40)
    salary = salary + over_salary

print(salary)
```

Comment: There are clearly a thousand ways this code could go...

Comment: No, I don't think so.  There are only a few sequences that make sense.

Answer (score -1):

`work_hours = int(input('Enter hours worked: ' ))` # here the input should be an integer

`if (work_hours <= 40):` #here you miss the ': mark

```
salary = 20 * work_hours
```

`if (work_hours > 40):`#here you miss the ': mark

```
 over_salary = 30 * (work_hours - 40)
reg_salary = 20 * 40 + over_salary

print("your total salary is:",reg_salar,"$")
```

I have found the some small errors in your code. You missed the ':' marks for if statement and the working hours should be insert as an integer. you entered as string. there are no arithmetic operations for strings.